# Disable the do not disturb banner on iOS 13 notification centre

Tags: ios, notifications, preferences, do-not-disturb

I like *do not disturb*, however, I updated my iPhone to iOS 13 and now there is a banner every time I turn on do not disturb. I know I turned on do not disturb, I don't want the banner.

How do I make the banner go away?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is no way.

When you swipe right on most notifications, there are the three options Manage, View, and Clear/Clear All. Manage is the one we are worried about, as it can permanently stop notifications.

Swiping right on the Do Not Disturb notification, though, only reveals two options, View and Clear. This shows there is no way to permanently disable it.

Answer (score 0):

Swipe right on the Do Not Disturb Notification to clear it.

Comment: I don't want to keep doing that, I want to configure do not disturb so the notification never shows up